# Script for displaying whole matching cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a HTML page that have a table with some text and a script that i used for searching text within that table. Like when i press a it highlight all text with a.
That script is successfully finding matching text within a table But i have a problem in this script like it display only start and last matching word in the table instead of displaying whole. Attached is my script and table.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function(){

  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) == 0){      
        cells.forEach(function(element){
            element.style.display = "none";
        });
        cells[i].style.background = "yellow";
        cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  continue;
  cells[i].hide();
    } else {
        cells[i].style.background = "white";
        cells.forEach(function(element){
          if(cells[i] !== element){
            element.style.display = "table-cell";
   cells[i].show();
          }
        }); 
    }    
  }

});
```

```html
<input id='myInput' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AAA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>BB</td>
     <td>BBB</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>CC</td>
     <td>CCC</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I can't understand what wrong i am doing and what is missing in my script. Kindly have a look on it and let me what i missed or wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed as your question does not appear to have anything to do with programming in Java. If I'm wrong, please comment back to me, and include `@hovercraft` in your message. I also added the [tag:javascript] tag since that seems to be the correct language used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your snippet you'll see an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: cells[i].show is not a function

This is because `show()` is a jQuery method and is not available on a DOMElement. You need to use `.style.display = 'table-cell'` in this case.

Similarly, `hide()` is a jQuery method too, although that didn't show the error as you call `continue;` before it, so it will never be hit. That call should be either removed (along with the redundant use of `continue`) or changed to `.style.display = 'none';`.

```js
var cells = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td"));
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {  
  cells.forEach(function(cell) {
    if (!search.value.trim()) {
      cell.style.background = "white";
      cell.style.display = 'table-cell';
    } else if (cell.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
      cell.style.background = 'yellow';
      cell.style.display = "table-cell";
    } else {
      cell.style.background = "white";
      cell.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id='myInput' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>AA</td>
    <td>AAA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>CC</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Finally note that checking for `indexOf() == 0` only matches the start of the string. If that was your intent, great. If you want to check *any* part of the string for a match, use `!= -1`

Comment: well i need to make change like it not only highlight all matching text and also hide other that are not matching thats why i trying to make somthing like that. if you can help me it would be great.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: i have problem with this script when i tried to search within a long table of some 500 cells...Kindly check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951625/remove-extra-cell-spaces