# Remove extra cell spaces

Tags: javascript

I have a script below:

```js
    var cells = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td"));
    var search = document.getElementById("myInput");
    
    search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        cells.forEach(function(cell) {
            if (!search.value.trim()) {
                cell.style.background = "white";
                cell.style.display = 'table-cell';
            } else if (cell.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                cell.style.background = 'yellow';
                cell.style.display = "table-cell";
            } else {
                cell.style.background = "white";
                cell.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<input id='myInput' type='text'>

<table id='myTable'>
                                    
                                    <tr>
             <td>a</td>
                                        <td>ab</td>
                                        <td>abs</td>
                                        <td>ador</td>
                                        <td>turous</td>
                                        <td>acac</td>
                                        <td>accle</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                                     <td>ed</td>
                                        <td>aced</td>
                                        <td>ate</td>
                                        <td>acg</td>
                                        <td>aci</td>
                                        <td>atic</td>
                                        <td>ive</td>
         </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>l</td>
                                        <td>pt</td>
                                        <td>able</td>
                                        <td>ad</td>
                                        <td>adoent</td>
                                        <td>ble</td>
                                        <td>d</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>ed</td>
                                        <td>a</td>
                                        <td>aate</td>
                                        <td>a</td>
                                        <td>aavating</td>
                                        <td>aive</td>
                                        <td>a</td>
         </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>d</td>
                                        <td>ng</td>
                                        <td>eable</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>alarmed</td>
                                        <td>ming</td>
                                        <td>t</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>ted</td>
                                        <td>ae</td>
                                        <td>all</td>
                                        <td>agjhistic</td>
                                        <td>akjhkjg</td>
                                        <td>hjious</td>
                                        <td>ample</td>
                                     </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>hjbsed</td>
                                        <td>ahkjng</td>
                                        <td>anhjkd</td>
                                        <td>ahjhnt</td>
                                        <td>ahjkjc</td>
                                        <td>a</td>
                                        <td>hjhed</td>
         </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>aghjed</td>
                                        <td>hjjal</td>
                                        <td>ghjmher</td>
                                        <td>amjhkiue</td>
                                        <td>ahkjus</td>
                                        <td>any</td>
                                        <td>ahmkjehensive</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>ajhjkjiate</td>
                                        <td>ahkjpt</td>
                                        <td>arctic</td>
                                        <td>arid</td>
                                        <td>aromatic</td>
                                        <td>artistic</td>
                                        <td>ashamed</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>assured</td>
                                        <td>astonishing</td>
                                        <td>athletic</td>
                                        <td>attached</td>
                                        <td>attentive</td>
                                        <td>atkjkjactive</td>
                                        <td>ahghbtere</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>bhkuhish</td>
                                        <td>hkjh</td>
                                       <td>bhkre</td>
                                        <td>barren</td>
                                        <td>basic</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>befsgdfgful</td>
                                        <td>bdsfsdfed</td>
                                        <td>dsfsdfved</td>
                                        <td>bedsfsfcial</td>
                                        <td>better</td>
                                        <td>best</td>
                                        <td>bdfsfitched</td>
                                    </tr>
</table>
```

I use this script for searching text with an HTML table. It have more than 500 cells like 100 rows and 5 columns etc. This script works well for finding text within a short table but when I search anything it also display gap of rows and columns, if i have a long table which has more than 500 cells.

Here I tried to used regular expressions like `\s` and `/g` but it doesn't work, may be I insert them on wrong place. Also I tried to change `cell.style.display = "table-cell";` with many other style but doesn't work.

Can any one properly guide me what and where I have to put exactly to get output properly without rows/columns gap if i have more than 500 cells and what that mean with syntax description.

Comment: Can u post a screen i am unable to understand clearly

Comment: i just update it with table kindly check it and let me know if you understand what gaps i want to remove

Comment: Set `border-collapse: collapse;` on the CSS for your `table` element; if you add this to the CSS you won't nee to add/remove it from the element(s) in JavaScript, it will automatically apply so long as a more-specific selector doesn't override it.

Comment: I used this...it show me result in line but remove cell space or column space... Can you guide me for it too.

Comment: Thanks i just did it my own by increasing 'width=100%' Thanks for solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this! =)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input"/>
<div class="print"></div>

<script>
var data = ['food', 'bar', 'google']; // your data

var fx = function(text) {
    var print = function(list,s) {
        var table = $('<table/>').css('width','100%');
        var x = 0;
        while (list[x]) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');
            while (list[x] && x < 5) {
             var td = $('<td/>').text(list[x])
             if(s == list[x]){
               td.css('background','red');
             }
                tr.append(td);
                x++;
            }
            table.append(tr);
        }
        $('.print').html(table);
    }

    if (typeof text === "undefined") {
        print(data, '');
    } else {
        var find = [];

        for (var i = 0; data[i]; i++) {
            if (data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) == 0) find[find.length] = data[i];
        }

        print(find,text);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('.input').keyup(function() {
        fx($(this).val());
    });
    fx();
});
</script>
```